# if-then statement with comparing two variables

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm just practicing a few lines of code this isn't for any specific program, but what's bugging me is that I want the input cursor to appear next to the print, but at the same time I need to define a variable in the same line which you can't do so I defined `e` as nothing which doesn't work because then `e` can't equal to `4`. Here's my code:

```
a = int(input("Give me a Number: "))
b = int(input("Give me another number: "))
c = b + a
def none():
    pass
e = none()
print("the sum of"), a, ("and"), b, ("is"), c

d = int(input("Please Insert your age here: "))
if d < 18:
    print("Sorry you must be 18 years or older to enter this site")
else:
    print("Welcome to www.example.com")
print("What is 2+2: "), e == int(input("")),
if e == 4:
    print("good Job!")
else:
    print("sorry no")
```

Comment: Instead of `e = none()` you can do `e = None`. `==` is the 'do these two things equal?' operator, NOT the assignment operator, which is a single `=`.

Comment: There's a valid general question here (Which comes from the OP's lack of experience with Python), but I can't seem to generalise the original in any sensible way. Voting to close as too localised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
print("What is 2+2: "); e=int(input(""))
```

You're current code is actually attempting to create a `tuple` of the result of `print` (`None`) and the result of the expression `e==int(input(""))` -- Which would normally be a boolean value if `e` didn't give you a `NameError` since it hasn't been defined yet.

---

Note that normally in these situations, you'd probably just do:

```
e = int(input("What is 2+2: "))
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that there's a difference between `e == int(input(""))` (which means *`e` is equal to the expression*) and `e = int(input(""))` (which means *assign the expression value to `e`*.

You need to assign the value to `e`